# How do you disable validation in jquery on a Stripe payment form

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I have a form with Stripe Elements that is a part of a wizard. I am using the Javascript from the Stripe API but I need to edit it to stop it from validating itself if I click the back button in my wizard. This is the code I have:

Javascript:

```
// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
        card.on('change', function (event) {
            var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            if (event.error) {
                displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
            } else {
                displayError.textContent = '';
            }
        });

        // Handle form submission.
        //var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            
            event.preventDefault();
            stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the user if there was an error.
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                } else {
                    // Send the token to your server.
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                }
            });
            
        });


        // Submit the form with the token ID.
        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
            // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
            var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
            form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

            // Submit the form
            form.submit();
        }
```

How do I edit this to skip validation when I click on the back button?

My button markup looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                                    <input type="submit" name="BtnPrevious" value="Previous" formnovalidate class="cancel btn btn-default" />

                                    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Payment</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>
```

I tried formnovalidate but I realized that this only works for HTML5 elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the back button `name=BtnPrevious`?  If so, does it need to be a submit input?  Put another way, can you make that button a simple anchor tag or a button that redirects on click instead of submitting the payment form?

Comment: I believe it has to be a submit input because in my wizard it uses a session token which stores the users progress in the form. Submit causes the post method in the mvc controller to either save and go on to the next page or go back to the previous